# Difference between Generic method with interface constraint and method with interface parameters

Tags: c#, generics

Can someone explain the difference if any between

```
    public void SwapIfGreater<T>(ref T lhs, ref T rhs) where T : System.IComparable
    {
        T temp;
        if (lhs.CompareTo(rhs) > 0)
        {
            temp = lhs;
            lhs = rhs;
            rhs = temp;
        }
    }
```

And

```
    public void SwapIfGreater(ref System.IComparable lhs, ref System.IComparable rhs)
    {
        System.IComparable temp;
        if (lhs.CompareTo(rhs) > 0)
        {
            temp = lhs;
            lhs = rhs;
            rhs = temp;
        }
    }
```

It seems to me as soon as you constrain your generic method to only accept parameters that implement an interface, you might as well use parameters of type interface.

Comment: Your second one allows arguments of two different types to be used (probably accidentally). It will also cause unnecessary boxing.

Comment: You're right, thank you

Comment: Actually your first one also causes unnecessary boxing of the `rhs` parameter when calling `CompareTo(object)`. You can avoid it by changing the constraint to `where T : IComparable<T>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The generic form will allow the compiler to do type checking to ensure that the arguments are of the same type.

Previously:
[`IComparable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd(v=vs.110).aspx) does not derive from `IComparable`. Hence, an object implementing `IComparable<T>` does not have to implement `IComparable`. These are incompatible with one another.

Comment: That's true, I copy pasted it from another site and didn't notice. I've edited the question.

Comment: Actually upon testing the compiler gives error if the arguments are not of the same type in the second one too.

Comment: @Tralli are both methods there? i believe the compiler chooses the best fit and generics fit that.